# Codensity monad is idempotent?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

Let $j: A \to B$ be a fully faithful functor.

When $j$ has a left adjoint $L$, the codensity monad $\text{Ran}_jj$ will coincide with the monad $jL$ and thus will be idempotent, because $A$ is reflective in $B$.

> Rem 1. Let $j$ be a fully faithful functor with a left adjoint. Then the codensity monad $\text{Ran}_jj$ is idempotent.

I was wondering if this is still true removing the assumption of having a left adjoint.

In a relatively trivial way, one can reformulate what I said in the following way.

> Rem 2. Let $j$ be a fully faithful functor. TFAE:
>
> - $\text{Ran}_jj$ preserve itself.
> - $\text{Ran}_jj$ is idempotent.

So, the question is finally the following,

> Q1. Let $j$ be a fully faithful functor, is it true that one of the two equivalent conditions in Rem 2 is verified? You can still assume that $j$ preserve all limits.
>
> Q2. If not, are there some natural assumptions that will make it true?

Answer (score 7):

The following addresses Q1 but not Q2.

Let $j: A \to B$ be the inclusion $Set_{\leq 3} \to Set$ of sets of cardinality $\leq 3$ into $Set$. Then the codensity monad for $j$ is the [ultrafilter monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ultrafilter#ultrafilters_form_a_monad) (as I learned [from Tom Leinster](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/09/where_do_ultrafilters_come_fro.html)-- I think this observation goes back to Isbell). This monad is not idempotent.

Comment: Hello Tim, I was partially aware of this counterexample, and of course, you are right. I will upvote the answer. I hope you will understand that I am much more into Q2, and that's why I can't accept this answer.